# How can I pixelate a jpg with java?

Tags: java, jpeg, pixel, pixelate

I'm trying to pixelate a JPEG with Java 6 and not having much luck. It needs to be with Java - not an image manipulation program like Photoshop, and it needs to come out looking old school - like this:

[image: Pixelated Image]

Can anybody help me?

Comment: ImageIO will help you loading and saving the image [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html) other than that it is just pixel manipulation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the `java.awt.image` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/package-summary.html)) and `javax.imageio` ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html)) APIs, you can easily loop through the image's pixels and perform the pixelation yourself.

Example code follows. You will need at least these imports: `javax.imageio.ImageIO`, `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`, `java.awt.image.Raster`, `java.awt.image.WritableRaster`, and `java.io.File`.

Example:

```
// How big should the pixelations be?
final int PIX_SIZE = 10;

// Read the file as an Image
img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));

// Get the raster data (array of pixels)
Raster src = img.getData();

// Create an identically-sized output raster
WritableRaster dest = src.createCompatibleWritableRaster();

// Loop through every PIX_SIZE pixels, in both x and y directions
for(int y = 0; y < src.getHeight(); y += PIX_SIZE) {
    for(int x = 0; x < src.getWidth(); x += PIX_SIZE) {

        // Copy the pixel
        double[] pixel = new double[3];
        pixel = src.getPixel(x, y, pixel);

        // "Paste" the pixel onto the surrounding PIX_SIZE by PIX_SIZE neighbors
        // Also make sure that our loop never goes outside the bounds of the image
        for(int yd = y; (yd < y + PIX_SIZE) && (yd < dest.getHeight()); yd++) {
            for(int xd = x; (xd < x + PIX_SIZE) && (xd < dest.getWidth()); xd++) {
                dest.setPixel(xd, yd, pixel);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Save the raster back to the Image
img.setData(dest);

// Write the new file
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", new File("image-pixelated.jpg"));
```

---

Edit: I thought I should mention -- the `double[] pixel` is, as far as I can tell, just the RGB color values. For example, when I dumped a single pixel, it looked like `{204.0, 197.0, 189.0}`, a light tan color.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the answer of @bchociej

I use in the pixel the dominant color of the zone defined by `PIX_SIZE`. It's not a perfect solution but it's a little better.

Here an example:

**Original:**
[image]

**Old Algorithm:**
[image]

**New Algorithm:**
[image]

#### Code sample

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;

public final class ImageUtil {

    public static BufferedImage pixelate(BufferedImage imageToPixelate, int pixelSize) {
        BufferedImage pixelateImage = new BufferedImage(
            imageToPixelate.getWidth(),
            imageToPixelate.getHeight(),
            imageToPixelate.getType());

        for (int y = 0; y < imageToPixelate.getHeight(); y += pixelSize) {
            for (int x = 0; x < imageToPixelate.getWidth(); x += pixelSize) {
                BufferedImage croppedImage = getCroppedImage(imageToPixelate, x, y, pixelSize, pixelSize);
                Color dominantColor = getDominantColor(croppedImage);
                for (int yd = y; (yd < y + pixelSize) && (yd < pixelateImage.getHeight()); yd++) {
                    for (int xd = x; (xd < x + pixelSize) && (xd < pixelateImage.getWidth()); xd++) {
                        pixelateImage.setRGB(xd, yd, dominantColor.getRGB());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return pixelateImage;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getCroppedImage(BufferedImage image, int startx, int starty, int width, int height) {
        if (startx < 0) startx = 0;
        if (starty < 0) starty = 0;
        if (startx > image.getWidth()) startx = image.getWidth();
        if (starty > image.getHeight()) starty = image.getHeight();
        if (startx + width > image.getWidth()) width = image.getWidth() - startx;
        if (starty + height > image.getHeight()) height = image.getHeight() - starty;
        return image.getSubimage(startx, starty, width, height);
    }

    public static Color getDominantColor(BufferedImage image) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> colorCounter = new HashMap<>(100);
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                int currentRGB = image.getRGB(x, y);
                int count = colorCounter.getOrDefault(currentRGB, 0);
                colorCounter.put(currentRGB, count + 1);
            }
        }
        return getDominantColor(colorCounter);
    }

    private static Color getDominantColor(Map<Integer, Integer> colorCounter) {
        int dominantRGB = colorCounter.entrySet().stream()
            .max((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1)
            .get()
            .getKey();
        return new Color(dominantRGB);
    }
}
```

#### How to use it

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
BufferedImage imagePixelated = ImageUtil.pixelate(img, PIX_SIZE);
ImageIO.write(imagePixelated, "jpg", new File("image-pixelated.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the code off hand, but if you can resize the image to 1/4 the original size then resample that back to the original size it should do the trick. Most image libraries can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the dominantColor function in Thibaut Mottet's answer, so instead of the most common color it returns the average RGB in that pixel
Original:
[image]

After:
[image]
It's not very optimized but you get the idea.

```
public static Color getDominantColor(BufferedImage image) {
    int sumR = 0, sumB = 0, sumG = 0, int sum2 = 0;
    int color = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            color = image.getRGB(x, y);
            Color c = new Color(color);
            sumR += c.getRed();
            sumB += c.getBlue();
            sumG += c.getGreen();
            sum2++;
        }
    }
    return new Color(sumR/sum2, sumG/sum2, sumB/sum2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Search "Close Pixelate" Project, probably this is what you need.

Comment: It looks perfect, except that's in javascript; I need java.

Answer (score 0):

Improving @thibaut-mottet answer, as I've got a compiler error on 'getDominantColor' method ('entry1' and 'entry2' not defined).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class ImageUtil {

    public static BufferedImage pixelate(BufferedImage imageToPixelate, int pixelSize) {
        BufferedImage pixelateImage = new BufferedImage(
            imageToPixelate.getWidth(),
            imageToPixelate.getHeight(),
            imageToPixelate.getType());

        for (int y = 0; y < imageToPixelate.getHeight(); y += pixelSize) {
            for (int x = 0; x < imageToPixelate.getWidth(); x += pixelSize) {
                BufferedImage croppedImage = getCroppedImage(imageToPixelate, x, y, pixelSize, pixelSize);
                Color dominantColor = getDominantColor(croppedImage);
                for (int yd = y; (yd < y + pixelSize) && (yd < pixelateImage.getHeight()); yd++) {
                    for (int xd = x; (xd < x + pixelSize) && (xd < pixelateImage.getWidth()); xd++) {
                        pixelateImage.setRGB(xd, yd, dominantColor.getRGB());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return pixelateImage;
    }

    public static BufferedImage getCroppedImage(BufferedImage image, int startx, int starty, int width, int height) {
        if (startx < 0) startx = 0;
        if (starty < 0) starty = 0;
        if (startx > image.getWidth()) startx = image.getWidth();
        if (starty > image.getHeight()) starty = image.getHeight();
        if (startx + width > image.getWidth()) width = image.getWidth() - startx;
        if (starty + height > image.getHeight()) height = image.getHeight() - starty;
        return image.getSubimage(startx, starty, width, height);
    }

    public static Color getDominantColor(BufferedImage image) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> colorCounter = new HashMap<>(100);
        for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
                int currentRGB = image.getRGB(x, y);
                int count = colorCounter.getOrDefault(currentRGB, 0);
                colorCounter.put(currentRGB, count + 1);
            }
        }
        return getDominantColor(colorCounter);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static Color getDominantColor(Map<Integer, Integer> colorCounter) {
        int dominantRGB = colorCounter.entrySet().stream()
            .max(new EntryComparator())
            .get()
            .getKey();
        return new Color(dominantRGB);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
class EntryComparator implements Comparator {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Entry<Integer, Integer> entry1 = (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>) o1;
        Entry<Integer, Integer> entry2 = (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>) o2;
        return (entry1.getValue() > entry2.getValue() ? 1 : -1);
    }
}
```

Use it exactly the same way:

```
img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
BufferedImage imagePixelated = ImageUtil.pixelate(img, PIX_SIZE);
ImageIO.write(imagePixelated, "jpg", new File("image-pixelated.jpg"));
```